# Can I calculate area of an irregular driveway using perimeter length?

Tags: driveway

can I measure the perimeter of an irregular driveway then simply convert this into area using the formula for area of a circle?

Comment: Well ... Ummm ... no ....

Comment: Trevor, imagine a circular pizza, or pancake, or whatever. Imagine trying to bring the edges of the circle inward to create an irregular shape. Can you do it without the circle wrinkling and lifting off the table? No. This illustrates how 1) area changes with shape, and 2) a circle has the lowest circumference to area ratio of any shape.

Comment: Also, if you were to post an aerial/satellite image of your driveway, plenty of folks would offer suggestions for calculation. You'd probably get a very precise answer if you included a reference dimension.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just had a coffee and a slice of cake. I've reduced cake circumference by about one sixth but now need to add on 2xradius to obtain 'perimeter'. Conclusion: Stack Exchange is a useful tool and coffee is a good stimulant. Trevor

Comment: Recommend closing as off-topic: this is a math question.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to measure smaller sections such as rectangles, squares, triangles and compute the area of those.  Then add those smaller areas up.

Also if it's more convenient you can measure a large area that includes non-driveway and compute that area, then also measure that smaller non-driveway portion separately and subtract it.

Comment: Tyson. thanks for that. I am able to break it down into smaller regular shapes as per your suggestion. See my comment to the other guys. Trevor

Comment: Thanks, If that is the solution for you please feel free to accept it as the answer.  In a normal browser, that means clicking the outlined green check mark on the left to make it a solid check mark (the different phone apps seem to vary a bit how marking as solution is presented).